# Search for string in multiline records

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to extract every row of a table whose column (let's call it "paragraph") matches a search string. The "paragraph" entry can (and always will) contain newlines. How can I select the correct rows?

For example, let's say I'm searching for every record that contains the word "jumps" in its "paragraph" column. How would I go about matching the following text:

> The quick brown
>
> fox jumps over
>
> the lazy dog

I'm using sqlite and it doesn't have regex support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE paragraph LIKE '%jump%';
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/03aba/1/0)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that this condition is not `SARGable` and its performance could be low.

Answer (score 1):

You Can write a query

```
Model_Name.where("column_name LIKE ?", "%search_value%")
```

In your case query should be like this

```
Model.where("paragraph LIKE ?", "%jumps%")
```

It returns the array of records which has `jumps` string into `paragraph` column.

May this helps you..